# How to test for significance in a ratio between two samples?

Tags: anova, t-test, f-test

I currently have two separate samples of objects, each of equal size. In each of these two samples, there is a subsample that exhibits a specific trait with some value of intensity. The value itself is not pertinent to what I'm trying to examine. What I'm finding is that one subsample has a larger number of objects that exhibit this trait. What I would like to do is apply some statistical test to find out how significant this difference is and to what degree of significance. Is there a test that will do this? Below is a histogram of my data for reference.

Fair warning, I have little experience with statistics, but I have been reading up on the ANOVA test. It seems like this type of test would be applied to the values themselves, which is not what I'm looking for. I'm unsure if I'm applying ANOVA incorrectly though if this is the appropriate test.

[image]

Comment: You have thought about the analysis, but I think ANOVA is not the right direction. Seems you want to analyze a 2-by-2 'contingency' table of counts. My Answer shows two possible tests with links. Most elementary statistics texts will explain one or both. I show how to do the tests using R statistical software, and give links to what I view as good explanations.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have counts for a $2 \times 2$ table such as the one below:

```
Trait \       Sample 1       Sample 2          TOTAL
----------------------------------------------------
Yes                 11             23            34
No                  89             77           166
----------------------------------------------------
TOTAL              100            100           200
```

Then you could use a [chi-squared test for independence](https://itl.nist.gov/div898/software/dataplot/refman1/auxillar/chistest.htm). The null
hypothesis is that proportion exhibiting the trait is independent of
sample.

You can do this test in R statistical software as follows:

```
DTA = rbind(c(11,23), c(89,77))
DTA
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   11   23
[2,]   89   77
chisq.test(DTA)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction

data:  DTA
X-squared = 4.2877, df = 1, p-value = 0.03839
```

Some people think the Yates continuity correction is too conservative, making
it less likely to reject the null hypothesis. The parameter `cor=F` of the
procedure `chisq.test` avoids this 'correction'. For my fake data, the
Yates correction makes little difference. The null hypothesis is rejected
at the 5% level either way.

Another possible test, used especially when some counts are rather small
as in my table, is to use [Fisher's Exact test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_exact_test). It is based on the hypergeometric
distribution. This test also rejects the null hypothesis with a P-value below 5%.

```
fisher.test(DTA)

        Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  DTA
p-value = 0.03729
alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.1712083 0.9549883
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
 0.4155832
```

Comment: Great, thank you so much for this! I believe the chi-squared test was exactly what I needed. Your answer also gave me my first introduction to R and RStudio, as I have been only working through Python. I appreciate your help! Hope all is well in these difficult times.